# #include<windows.h> not found - how to fix this for using in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, header-files

I have some C Code which includes "windows.h" header file. By trying to compile the Code, I get the error that windows.h is not found. I guess this is because I am using Ubuntu 20.04, such that the compiler doesn't know the header file. Is there a way to fix the problem?

Comment: what functions from windows.h do you need. comment out the include and see what breaks in the build

Comment: `rm -f offending-source.c` — it will be easiest that way.  IOW, it will be hard to compile a source file that expects to use `<windows.h>` on Linux.  You can create code that is portable between Windows and Linux, but the typical, randomly chosen source file cannot handle that.  You can look at the build instructions for the software — that may help too.  It might be that the code can be configured to compile on Windows by default but also compile on Linux by setting some flags — probably `-DPLATFORM=LINUX` as a compiler option, or some other vaguely equivalent mechanism.

Comment: Two options. 1) The file was included but not actually needed. Remove the include and be happy. 2) The file was included because the program includes WIN32 API calls. Remove the include, sort through the errors, and replace Windows specific code with a Linux compatible equivalent. If you're careful, and lucky, you may be able to replace the Windows specific code with something portable that works in either.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I have also heard that people link code against the [WINE](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/wine/info) libraries. About 10 years ago, I heard that there are even ports of the WINE libraries for non-x86 machines to allow you to compile Windows programs on these machines. Running Windows .EXE files (what is normally done using WINE) is of course not possiblie on non-x86 machines.